# How To Apply Google Apps Script For Multiple Dependent Drop Downs To Several Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Multiple Dependent Drop-Down Lists For Several Sheets

I am attempting to have the same dependent dropdown lists available on three sheets within the same document. So far it only works on sheet titled "Transactions 6080". What do I need to add to my code to make it work for sheets "Transactions 6586" and "Transactions 1002" as well?

```
var transactionsWsName = "Transactions 6080";
var categoriesWsName = "Categories";
var firstLevelColumn = 6;
var secondLevelColumn = 7;
var thirdLevelColumn = 8;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(transactionsWsName);
var wsCategories = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(categoriesWsName);
var categories = wsCategories.getRange(6, 6,wsCategories.getLastRow()-5, 3).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === transactionsWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);   
  } else if(wsName === transactionsWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);    
  }
}

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredCategories = categories.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredCategories.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }   
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
    var filteredCategories = categories.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredCategories.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }   
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your code referring to the other sheets you mentioned, "Transactions 6586" or "Transactions 1002". If you want the exact same thing to happen in each sheet, you'll need to add those other sheets to your *if* statement in the *onEdit* function, for example:

```
if((wsName === 'Transactions 6080' || 'Transactions 6586' || 'Transactions 1002') && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);   
  } else if(wsName === transactionsWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);    
  }
```

If those are the only three sheets in the spreadsheet, you may want to consider using an array rather than writing out each name:

```
var transactionSheets = [];
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i in sheets) {
   transactionSheets[i] = sheets[i].getName();
}
```

Then you'd check the name of the edited sheet against each of the values in the array. This will save you time if you add additional sheets to the spreadsheet down the road.